# Struts2 - forward by annotation with dynamic parameter

Tags: java, dynamic, parameters, struts2, annotations

I'm trying to forward action result to another action with dynamic parameter. The passed parameter to second action has `""` value.

```
@Result(name = "success", 
    location = "edit_service_subscribers", 
        type = "redirect", 
      params = {"selectedServiceId", "%{serviceId}"}
)
```

I declared `private String serviceId;` with getter and setter in first action, 
and `private String selectedServiceId;` with getter and setter in second action.

Problem is with filling the value of parameter. But where?

How can I pass value of global variable in action class to redirected parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. use [`RedirectAction`](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/redirect-action-result.html) to redirect to another Action. 

   [`Redirect`](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/redirect-result.html) result is used to redirect to non-action URLs (like
   external URLs).
2. This is not OGNL: instead of

   ```
   "%{serviceId}"
   ```

   use

   ```
   "${serviceId}"
   ```

Comment: There is different problem. I agree, there should be used redirectAction, but my second ACTION "edit_service_subscribers" is launched and parameter "selectedServiceId" is empty. I think that the problem is in first ACTION where I fill value of parameter. Is enaugh to declare global variable and fill the value?

Answer (score 3):

I already solved it. I don't know how, but there disappeared GETer... So much time spend for that...

My actual code is:

```
})
@Results({
    @Result(name = "success", type = "redirectAction",params = {"namespace", "/", "selectedServiceId", "${serviceId}", "actionName", "edit_service_subscribers"})
})
```

It works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your line with this

```
@Result(name = "success", location = "/department.jsp",
        type="redirect", params={"yourkey", "${passingvalue}"})
```